# Keep getting null on create user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys i have this php jquery ajax create user form that passes the create details to the php script but i keep getting null on the post variables anyhelp would be appreciated! code below

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="createForm">
<input type="text" name="createUser" class="form-control" placeholder="Brugernavn*" id="createUser">
 <input type="email" name="createUserEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" id="createUserEmail">
<input type="password" name="createUserPass" id="createUserPass" class="form-control" placeholder="Kodeord*" id="createUserPass">
<input type="password" name="confirmUserPass" id="confirmUserPass" class="form-control" placeholder="Bekræft Kodeord*" id="createUserPass">
<h4 id="newsletterText">Vil du have vores nyhedsbrev?</h4>
<select name="newsletter" id="newsletter" class="form-control"><option value="yes">Ja tak!</option><option value="nej" selected="">Nej tak</option></select>
<input type="submit" name="submitCreateUser" class="btn btn-success" id="submitCreateUser" value="Opret!">
    </form>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submitCreateUser").click(function(){
 var username = $("#createUser").val();
   var email = $("#createUserEmail").val();
    var pass = $("#createUserPass").val();
      var cPass = $("#createUserPassC").val();
        var newsletter = $("#newsletter").val();

   $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "createuserajax.php",
 data: "username="+username+"&email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&cPass="+cPass,
 success: function(html){
  if(html=='true')
  {
alert(username);


 }
 else
  {

  }
 },

 }
  );

});

});
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['pass'];


var_dump($username);
 $securePassword = md5(($password));
    $sqlInsertUser = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$securePassword')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlInsertUser);
```

Comment: Why would `html` be `"true"`, the PHP script never echos anything ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks for your comment! i know i dont echo anything but thats is a work in progress :)

Comment: The form probably submits the regular way, as there's nothing stopping it. That means the page reloads before the ajax call is made, and there are no inputs with the name `username` in the form.

Comment: Sidenote: md5 isn't secure. Use CRYPT_BLOWFISH or password_hash()

Comment: @adeneo how will i fix this? :)

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adeneo says, your html form is likely being submitted the standard way before the ajax call is made because you haven't prevent the default behaviour. try the below instead:

---

Alternatively, you could remove `<input type="submit" name="submitCreateUser" class="btn btn-success" id="submitCreateUser" value="Opret!">` and give the `id="submitCreateUser"` to some other element like a custom button or link. When you click and `input` tag with the type `submit` it will submit the accompanying form the normal way by default. This happens **before** the click handler hears the click so the form is submitted before your code call the ajax. Use a different element for the click and this wont happen

**And don't forget** for this to work at all, your `php` file must echo something which will be returned in your `html` variable, without that `html` will never be true and nothing will ever happen.

**Part of your problem** is that your input elements, specifically the ones for the password and password checks both have two separate id tags the first is duplicated and the second is a different id altogether. Also in your jquery, when you try to get the id check value you use another, different, id.

Here is a test page that address all of these issues and works as expected:

http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/createuserajax.html

**The test php code:**

```
<?php

  if( isset($_POST) )
  {
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['pass'];

     echo   'username --'.$username.', email --'.$email.', password --'.$password;
  }

?>
```

**The html code:**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="createForm">
  <input type="text" name="createUser" class="form-control" placeholder="Brugernavn*" id="createUser">
  <input type="email" name="createUserEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" id="createUserEmail">
  <input type="password" name="createUserPass" id="createUserPass" class="form-control" placeholder="Kodeord*">
  <input type="password" name="confirmUserPass" id="confirmUserPass" class="form-control" placeholder="Bekræft Kodeord*" >
  <!-- these lines had duplicated id tags-->
  <h4 id="newsletterText">Vil du have vores nyhedsbrev?</h4>
  <select name="newsletter" id="newsletter" class="form-control">
    <option value="yes">Ja tak!</option>
    <option value="nej" selected="">Nej tak</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submitCreateUser" class="btn btn-success" id="submitCreateUser" value="Opret!">
</form>
```

**The jQuery code:**

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitCreateUser").click(function( event ) { // add event var here
        event.preventDefault(); // add this line to stop the form from submitting the normal way before the ajax call
        var username = $("#createUser").val();
        var email = $("#createUserEmail").val();
        var pass = $("#createUserPass").val();
        var cPass = $("#confirmUserPass").val(); // you were using "#createUserPassC" here in error
        var newsletter = $("#newsletter").val();
        var datastring = "username=" + username + "&email=" + email + "&pass=" + pass + "&cPass=" + cPass +"&newsletter=" + newsletter;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "createuserajax.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(html) {
                if (html) { // changed this line from "if (html == 'true')" just for testing  
                    alert(html); // changed this line from "alert(username);" just for testing  


                } else {
                    alert('something went wrong!');
                }
            },

        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! however it does not work when i do this my submit button just becomes inactive? :)

Comment: Np, testing something now :)